# how do i pass information to second form object

Tags: vb.net

Good Morning all.

I have been working on this forever. but I am down to the very end. I need to get this submitted for may class Sunday.

I have a button that sends my data to the usb drive and I need to send it to a list on a second form.  How do I pass this over.

Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub btnTestResults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTestResults.Click

    '   Sends data to the frmresults form three, and creates the "consult.txt file on a
    '   USB drive for the Nurse can contact the patients.

    Dim objWriter As New IO.StreamWriter("e:\consult.txt")
    Dim frmThird As New frmElevatedResults
    Dim intHighCholesterol As Integer = 200I

    '   Write the file line by line until the file is completed.
    If IO.File.Exists("e:\consult.txt") Then
        If _intCholesterolLevel(intCount) < intHighCholesterol Then
            objWriter.WriteLine(_strNames(intCount))
            objWriter.WriteLine(_intCholesterolLevel(intCount))



        Else
            MsgBox("The file is not available. 
                    Please restart the program when the file is available", , "Error")
            objWriter.Close()
        End If

    End If


    Hide()
    frmThird.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have already an instance of _frmElevatedResults_ displayes when this code runs? And, to which form this code belongs?

Comment: This code is on form 1, and does not display there.  I have created a lst box on frmElevatedResults. but I can  not get the data to go there when the button is clicked.  it does send the data to the usb drive.

Comment: Do I need to create a lstbox on form 1 and then pass the information to form 3. and then just hide the lst.box on form 1?

Comment: You could define the Listbox as public class member on the frmElevatedResults and set it on form 1. Then show the second form.

Comment: please forgive me, I am in my 6 week of this course. would that be     public shared lstResults ?

Comment: Forms are just classes.  Rather than other things fiddling with controls, create a method that allows you to pass data to the form.  Then in that form method do whatever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make the listbox public on `frmElevatedResults`:

1. Add the listbox control via Toolbox to your `frmElevatedResults` (if not already done).
2. In the Project-Explorer click on `Show all Files`.
3. Open `frmElevatedResults.Designer.vb`
4. Find the listbox controle e.g. `listBox1 as ListBox`
5. Make it public: `public listBox1 as ListBox`

(I would have included screens but my VS is not in English).

On your first form you can now use:

```
Dim frmThird As New frmElevatedResults
...
frmThird.listBox1.Items.Add(string.concat(_strNames(intCount), 
                            " - ", 
                            _intCholesterolLevel(intCount))
...
Hide()
frmThird.Show()
```

or whatever you want to put in there.